# Cannot find template when trying to use embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

I am trying to do the sample project for ejs from their website (http://embeddedjs.com/), and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a very simple app that looks like:

```
/tryejs/index.html
/tryejs/template.ejs
/tryejs/ejs_production.js
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Try EJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var data = { title: "Try EJS!" };
        var fragment = new EJS({url: 'template.ejs'}).render(data);
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild = fragment;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and template.ejs has only (nothing else):

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
```

What am I missing?

I keep getting the following error:
"Uncaught There is no template at template.ejs"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to be running it on a server for it to run! I ran it on a Node server and it works just fine. I guess ejs makes server requests to access templates...